# Matching hash key in hash with multiple keys

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I want get the values from a hash that uses two keys using a regex just on the second key. This is what I have:

```
use List::Util qw<first>;

$key1 = "key";

my $value = $hash{$key1}{ ( first { m/teen/ } keys %hash ) || '' };
```

Comment: `print Dumper \%hash;` and what values you want to collect.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The code does not work.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't but you have to describe your expectations.

Comment: did you try `print "$hash{'key'}\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my %hash = ( 'key1' => 'result',
             'key2' => 'wrong');

foreach my $key (keys %hash) { 
    print "$key, $hash{$key}\n" if $hash{$key} =~ /result/;
}
```

prints:

```
key1, result
```

Edit - at a second glance, although I'm still baffled by your code and question, it appears that you want to find a value associated with a particular key, in this case `'key1'`:

```
print "key1 = $hash{'key1'}\n";
```

which prints:

```
key1 = result
```